# "Separating the variables" in a 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking at the following ODE (obtained in order to use the similarity reduction method when solving the Heat Equation):
$$
y'' + \frac{1}{2}xy'=0
$$
IC/BC: $y(0) = 1, y(\infty) = 0$

The text says:
"Separating the variables, we find that:
$$y'(x) = Ce^{-x^2/4}$$ for some constant $C$."

**How do I go about getting the result presented above?**

In particular I am confused as this is not the separation of variables (s.o.v) I have seen before e.g.:

- in the 1st order ODE where you integrate out both sides
- in the Heat Equation solution where the ratio of both $X$ and $T$ functions is the same on both sides of equation hence they must equal to the constant $\lambda$.

Comment: Corrected that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that $y'\not\equiv 0$, make the change of variables $u = y'$ so that we get
\begin{align*}
u' + \frac{xu}{2} = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow u' = -\frac{xu}{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{u'}{u} = -\frac{x}{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \ln|u| = -\frac{x^{2}}{4} + c\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u = \pm\exp(c)\exp\left(-\frac{x^{2}}{4}\right)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u = C\exp\left(-\frac{x^{2}}{4}\right)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y' = C\exp\left(-\frac{x^{2}}{4}\right)
\end{align*}

where $C\in\textbf{R}\backslash\{0\}$. Since $y'\equiv 0$ is also a solution, we can consider that $C\in\textbf{R}$.

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: if you expand the second line to $\frac{du}{udx}= -\frac{1}{2}x$ the separation of variables becomes very clear. Thanks!

Comment: @userPrimeNumber you are welcome ! I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

$$y'' + \frac{1}{2}xy'=0$$
The DE is linear...
The integrating factor is:
$$\mu=e^{\frac {x^2}{4}}$$
$$y''e^{\frac {x^2}{4}} + \frac{1}{2}xe^{\frac {x^2}{4}}y'=0$$
$$\left(y'e^{\frac {x^2}{4}} \right)'=0$$
Integrate.

Comment: Useful demonstration of using the integrating factor technique for second order ODEs.

Comment: Yes thank you  @userPrimeNumber